# how to get header and detail row from a result set?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have these three tables .

```
CREATE TABLE Employees (
    EmpID INT IDENTITY, 
    EmpName VARCHAR(100)
)  
GO    
INSERT INTO Employees(EmpName)  
SELECT 'John Torres' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Irina Williams'

SELECT * FROM Employees
GO

CREATE TABLE PayrollWeek(
    WeekID INT IDENTITY, 
    EmpID INT,
    WeekStart DATETIME,
    WeekEnd DATETIME
)  
GO    
INSERT INTO PayrollWeek(EmpID,WeekStart,WeekEnd)  
SELECT 1,'11-20-2011','11-26-2011' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'11-27-2011','12-03-2011' UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'11-27-2011','12-03-2011'

SELECT * FROM PayrollWeek
GO

CREATE TABLE EmployeeVisits(
    ID INT, 
    EmpID INT,
    VisitDate DATETIME,
    StartTime VARCHAR(5),
    EndTime VARCHAR(5),
    EarningCode VARCHAR(100)
)  
GO    
INSERT INTO EmployeeVisits(ID,EmpID,VisitDate,StartTime,EndTime,EarningCode)  
SELECT 1,1,'11-20-2011','10:00','12:00','Sat-Sun1' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,1,'11-21-2011','13:30','16:00','Mon-Fri1' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,1,'11-22-2011','14:00','15:00','Mon-Fri1' UNION ALL
SELECT 4,1,'11-24-2011','10:00','14:00','Mon-Fri1' UNION ALL
SELECT 5,1,'11-25-2011','13:30','16:00','Mon-Fri1' UNION ALL
SELECT 6,1,'11-26-2011','14:00','15:00','Sat-Sun1' UNION ALL
SELECT 7,2,'11-27-2011','09:00','11:00','Sat-Sun1' UNION ALL
SELECT 8,2,'11-28-2011','07:00','12:00','Mon-Fri1' UNION ALL
SELECT 9,2,'11-29-2011','09:00','11:00','Mon-Fri1' UNION ALL
SELECT 10,2,'12-03-2011','07:00','12:00','Sat-Sun1'
```

Expected Result is this

```
 RecordType EmpId   EmpName WeekStart   Weekend EarningCode Hour
    H            1     John Torres  11/20/2011  11/26/2011      
    D                                                  Sat-Sun1 3
    D                                                  Mon-Fri1 10
    H            2   Irina Williams 11/27/2011  12/3/2011       
    D                                                  Sat-Sun1 7
    D                                                  Mon-Fri1 7
```

Comment: you should handle this on ui

Comment: @ughai yes you may be right  but I  need to write it in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my answer I try this using `Union`, `Group By`  .

```
SELECT 'H' AS RecordType
        ,emp.EmpID
        ,EmpName
        ,Cast(MIN(WeekStart) AS VARCHAR(106)) AS StartTime
        ,cast(Max(VisitDate) AS VARCHAR(106)) AS EndTime
        ,'' AS EarningCode
        ,'' AS TimeDiff
    FROM EmployeeVisits E
    JOIN PayrollWeek P ON e.EmpID = P.EmpID
    JOIN Employees Emp ON Emp.EmpID = e.EmpID
    GROUP BY emp.EmpID
        ,EmpName

    UNION

    SELECT 'D' AS RecordType
        ,EmpID
        ,'' AS EmpName
        ,'' AS StartTime
        ,'' AS EndTime
        ,EarningCode
        ,cast(sum(dateDiff(MINUTE, StartTime, EndTime)) / 60 AS VARCHAR(100)) AS TimeDiff
    FROM EmployeeVisits
    GROUP BY EmpID
        ,EarningCode
    ORDER BY EmpID
        ,RecordType DESC
```